# How to transform collections correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, windows-runtime

```
class Anime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I have two collections of type Anime. Let's assume they called a1 and a2. I want to get 3 collections of type Anime:

1. Items which are only in a1
2. Items which are only in a2
3. Items which are in both collections

How can I achieve this? I think I should do something with linq and Id value, but I didn't manage to find adequate solution.
By the way, Id value is unique for each anime series(if two items has the same Id, they represent the same series).

Comment: See `IEnumerable<T>` methods like Intersect, Except, Union

Comment: And create `IComparer` for the `Anime` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you implement *GetHashCode* and *Equals* method, you can easily write your code with the help of link.

```
class Anime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var anime = obj as Anime;
        if (anime == null) return false;

        return this.Id == anime.Id;
    }
}
```

Now it can be done as

```
var a1 = new List<Anime>()
{
    new Anime() { Id=1, Title="Title1" },
    new Anime() { Id=2, Title="Title2" },
    new Anime() { Id=3, Title="Title3" },
    new Anime() { Id=4, Title="Title4" }
};

var a2 = new List<Anime>()
{
    new Anime() { Id=1, Title="Title1" },
    new Anime() { Id=3, Title="Title3" },
    new Anime() { Id=5, Title="Title5" }
};

var q1 = a1.Except(a2).ToList();
var q2 = a2.Except(a1).ToList();
var q3 = a1.Intersect(a2).ToList();
```

Comment: And if you can't for some reason implement those methods on the object itself, you can create a class that implements `IEqualityComparer`, and then call the `Except` and `Intersect` overloads that accept an `IEqualityComparer` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple way of doing it, which has the added benefit of working in both LINQ over objects and LINQ over SQL:

```
var q1=a1.Where(a=>!a2.Any(b=>b.Id==a.Id));
var q2=a2.Where(a=>!a1.Any(b=>b.Id==a.Id));
var a3=a1.Where(a=>a2.Any(b=>b.Id==a.Id));
```

From LINQPAD:

```
class Anime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var a1=new Anime[]{new Anime {Id=1,Title="Title1"},new Anime {Id=2,Title="Title2"}};
    var a2=new Anime[]{new Anime {Id=2,Title="Title2"},new Anime {Id=3,Title="Title3"}};

    var q1=a1.Where(a=>!a2.Any(b=>b.Id==a.Id));
    var q2=a2.Where(a=>!a1.Any(b=>b.Id==a.Id));
    var q3=a1.Where(a=>a2.Any(b=>b.Id==a.Id));
    q1.Dump();
    q2.Dump();
    q3.Dump();
}
```

Result:

[image]

You could also set up a custom IEqualityComparer and use Intersects, but that's usually more difficult than it is worth in all except high performance situations, and doesn't work with LINQ over SQL:

```
class Anime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}

class AnimeComparer: IEqualityComparer<Anime>
{
    public bool Equals(Anime a1, Anime a2)
    {
        return (a1.Id==a2.Id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Anime a)
    {
        return a.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var a1=new Anime[]{new Anime {Id=1,Title="Title1"},new Anime {Id=2,Title="Title2"}};
    var a2=new Anime[]{new Anime {Id=2,Title="Title2"},new Anime {Id=3,Title="Title3"}};

    var ac=new AnimeComparer();
    var q1=a1.Except(a2,ac);
    var q2=a2.Except(a1,ac);
    var q3=a1.Intersect(a2,ac);
    q1.Dump();
    q2.Dump();
    q3.Dump();
}
```

Third approach is to use an extension method.  This also will not likely work with LINQ over SQL, but doesn't require modifications to any classes, or custom IEqualityComparers if you have a large variety of object types:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, Func<TSource, TSource, bool> comparer)
    {
        return first.Where(x => !second.Any(y => comparer(x, y)));
    }
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, Func<TSource, TSource, bool> comparer)
    {
        return first.Where(x => second.Any(y => comparer(x, y)));
    }
}

class Anime
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var a1=new Anime[]{new Anime {Id=1,Title="Title1"},new Anime {Id=2,Title="Title2"}};
    var a2=new Anime[]{new Anime {Id=2,Title="Title2"},new Anime {Id=3,Title="Title3"}};

    var q1=a1.Except(a2,(b1,b2)=>b1.Id==b2.Id);
    var q2=a2.Except(a1,(b1,b2)=>b1.Id==b2.Id);
    var q3=a1.Intersect(a2,(b1,b2)=>b1.Id==b2.Id);
    q1.Dump();
    q2.Dump();
    q3.Dump();
}
```

A fourth option is to use [morelinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq), which combines the simplicity of no custom IEqualityComparers with very high performance (but still not compatible with LINQ over SQL):

```
class Anime
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var a1=new Anime[]{new Anime {Id=1,Title="Title1"},new Anime {Id=2,Title="Title2"}};
    var a2=new Anime[]{new Anime {Id=2,Title="Title2"},new Anime {Id=3,Title="Title3"}};

    var q1=a1.ExceptBy(a2,k=>k.Id);
    var q2=a2.ExceptBy(a1,k=>k.Id);
    var q3=a1.ExceptBy(q1,k=>k.Id);
    q1.Dump();
    q2.Dump();
    q3.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the down vote with no explanation, but the above code works just fine.